# Get User in Powershell / Linux

Tags: linux, powershell, centos

under windows i can get the currently logged in user on a remote (windows) machine with

```
Get-WmiObject –ComputerName [machine name] –Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object UserName
```

I now do have a CentOS 8 server with Powershell installed

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-7
```

How do i get the same function only for my linux machine?
The target [machine name] is always a windows machine with one logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

It is not as straightforward because linux does not have WMI.

With session import (my favorite if you want to use other commands based on WMI/CIM) :

```
$MyCred = Get-Credential
$mySession = New-PsSession -ComputerName MyWindowsMachine -Credential $myCred -Authentication Negotiate

# Starting Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8
Import-PsSession -Session $mySession -Prefix PSS -Module CimCmdlets
(Get-PSSCimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName

# Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows 7 and above
Import-PsSession -Session $mySession -Prefix PSS -Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
(Get-PSSWmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName
```

Simplier with `Invoke-Command` :

```
$MyCred = Get-Credential
$mySession = New-PsSession -ComputerName MyWindowsMachine -Credential $myCred -Authentication Negociate

# Starting Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8
Invoke-Command -Session $mySession -ScriptBlock { (Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName }

# Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows 7 and above
Invoke-Command -Session $mySession -ScriptBlock { (Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName }
```

Note that, for both options, your Windows Client needs to trust your linux. If your linux is not inside the same kerberos domain, you need to configure all Windows clients trustedhosts :

```
Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value LinuxPC
```